# How to enter wifi-password on ev3dev?

Tags: ev3dev, wi-fi

After successfully installing [ev3dev](http://www.ev3dev.org) and getting the USB connection working I now want to get my wifi-dongle working (or rather connecting). The dongle is successfully found and my LAN is displayed.

But as expected I need to type a password, this is the problem! How do I insert a password in the brickman interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the password dialog pops up, press ENTER (the middle button) to open an on screen keyboard.

[image: password] [image: keyboard]

Comment: It was to easy. I was probably very tired yesterday :) Thanks!